# KeyEventArgs not responding to pressing escape button

Tags: c#, keyboard-events, keyeventargs

I have a WinForm application in which i whish to use the escape button to close a control. I have created an event on KeyPress and this works when i use any other key than Escape.

```
private void ProductsView_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char) Keys.B  || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape)
    {
        //Magic happens
    }
}
```

If i press 'b' everything works as expected, but if i press 'Escape', the event is not fired (yes, my escape button works).
I have no clue what could cause this problem and i have also tried KeyUp & KeyDown events.

Comment: Use `KeyDown` or `KeyUp` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can created nested control and override method ProcessCmdKey:

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Escape:
            {
                //...magic
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!
This solved my problem, you are a life saver ! ;)